# How to resume a paused CountDownTimer in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, countdowntimer

The idea is to make a Chess Clock. But the problem is resuming a paused instance of CountDownTimer without resetting or creating a new one.

The first action is touch in the "white button" and the method "startTimerBlack" is called: the black timer start running, the white timer is paused.

When "black button" is touched the "startTimerWhite" is called: the white timer start running, the black timer pause.

When white button is touched again the black timer should resume, but isnt.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    enum class TimerState {
        Stopped, Paused, Running
    }

    private lateinit var timerWhite: CountDownTimer
    private lateinit var timerBlack: CountDownTimer
    private var timerStateWhite = TimerState.Stopped
    private var timerStateBlack = TimerState.Stopped
    private var secondsRemaining = 0L

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        buttonWhite.setOnClickListener { v ->
            println("white")
            startTimerBlack()
        }
        buttonBlack.setOnClickListener { v ->
            println("black")
            startTimerWhite()
        }
    }

    private fun startTimerWhite() {
        if(timerStateBlack != TimerState.Stopped) {
            timerBlack.cancel()
            timerStateBlack = TimerState.Paused
        }

        timerStateWhite = TimerState.Running
        timerWhite = object : CountDownTimer(1000 * 1000, 1000) {
            override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {
                secondsRemaining = millisUntilFinished / 1000
                buttonWhite.text = secondsRemaining.toString()
            }
            override fun onFinish() {}
        }.start()
    }

    private fun startTimerBlack() {
    if(timerStateWhite != TimerState.Stopped) {
        timerWhite.cancel()
        timerStateWhite = TimerState.Paused
    }

    timerStateBlack = TimerState.Running
    timerBlack = object : CountDownTimer(secondsRemaining, 1000) {
        override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {
            secondsRemaining = millisUntilFinished / 1000
            buttonBlack.text = secondsRemaining.toString()
        }

        override fun onFinish() {

        }
    }.start()
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
timerWhite = object : CountDownTimer(1000 * 1000, 1000)
```

If I am correct, the above always resets your `secondsRemaining` to `999000 / 1000 = 999` once timerWhite starts its first tick. In consequence, the whiteTimer always restarts at value 1000s, and the blackTimer always starts at the time that's left when the whiteTimer was stopped.

If I understood chess clock correctly though, you should have separate times saved for each timer. Like below:

```
private var whiteSecondsRemaining = 1000
private var blackSecondsRemaining = 1000
...
timerWhite = object : CountDownTimer(whiteSecondsRemaining , 1000) {
    // update whiteSecondsRemaining in onTick()
}
...
timerBlack = object : CountDownTimer(blackSecondsRemaining , 1000) {
    // update blackSecondsRemaining in onTick()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it could be done within one `Thread` and time for both players. Since it's handled in different way. Check out this very simple code to do it.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private val DELAY = TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(3)
    private val chessTimer = ChessTimer("Sample")

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        startTask()
        chessTimer.start()
    }

    private fun startTask() {
        Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed({
            chessTimer.changeTime()
            startTask()
        }, DELAY)
    }

    private class ChessTimer(name: String) : Thread(name) {
        var time1 = TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(3)
        var time2 = TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(3)

        var active: Boolean = true
        var startTime : Long = 0

        override fun run() {
            var whichAction = active

            while (true) {
                synchronized(this) {
                    if (active != whichAction) {
                        /**
                         * Action was changed!
                         */
                        val delta = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime
                        Log.d("Sample", "Current time: ${System.currentTimeMillis()} Delta $delta")
                        if (whichAction) time1 -= delta
                                else time2 -= delta

                        whichAction = active
                        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
                        Log.d(
                            "Sample", "Time one $time1." +
                                    " Time second $time2"
                        )
                    }

                }
            }
        }

        override fun start() {
            startTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
            active = true
            super.start()
        }

        fun changeTime() {
            synchronized(this) {
                Log.d("Sample", "Time: ${System.currentTimeMillis()} ")
                active = !active
            }
        }
    }
}
```